# Log Transformation return p-value non-significant

Tags: r, regression, logarithm, ecology

I'm evaluating if the species-area relationship get improved, using Log (SR) and Log (Area) instead of the original data?

In this case, after log-transformation the p-value return non-significant for species-area relationships.

Which do you think is the reason behind this?

This the plot:
[image]

Comment: Based on the panels, the (linear) relationship is insignificant for *both* original and log-transformed data.

Comment: Very small sample and two awkward values. How do you explain species richness of 0: bare or empty sites?

Comment: Does the measurement method create larger uncertainty for larger areas? This appears to be count data, so you should use an [appropriate GLM](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pscl/vignettes/countreg.pdf).

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you have 8 data points. When you have such a small data set, for something to be statistically significant it would have to be a very strong relationship.  You don't have a very strong relationship.

Second, it seems like you have a nonlinear relationship for 7 points, with one outlier.  With only 7 data points on the curve, it's hard to tell, but it doesn't even look quadratic - for one thing, there is a floor effect.

Third, species richness is a count - according to definitions I found in a couple places.  Therefore, you should not take the log of SR + 1, you should use a count regression model - probably negative binomial; you might actually need a zero-inflated negative binomial, but that will be very hard to fit with only 8 data points.

Finally, don't rely too much on p values.

Comment: Species richness of zero would mean no observed species (or taxa, more generally). See my comment on OP's question. You visited a site and saw no elephants: no difficulty in ecological principle about that. It's clearly true that observed zeros sit awkwardly with log transformations. In my experience biologists are often taught +1 as a fudge and are less queasy about it than I would be.

Comment: Hi Nick, yeah, I am leery of that fudge, too.  But for counts I am especially leery.  After all, we have count models!